# Transfering References from MS-Word to LaTeX Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, msword, ieee-style, word-to-latex

I have some references (not in bibliography format, but made manualy IEEE-style) that I need to transfer from Word to LaTeX. How can I achieve this? I am using IEEEtrans class. A sample code below

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{IEEEhowto:hans1}
N.~Name, "The M.Sc. Thesis Titles in quotation", M.Sc. Thesis, Y University, ISBN, City, Country, Year.
\bibitem{IEEEhowto:hans2}
R.~Name, "The PhD Thesis Titles in quotation", PhD Thesis, Y University, ISBN, City, Country, Year.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 9 references in the reference section of my word document, made IEEE-style. I don't use any other TeX file i.e. a bib file. I have it inside my main IEEEtrans class document. I tried some online word to latex reference converters alike below, but doesn't work properly: http://www.snowelm.com/~t/doc/tips/makebib.en.html

Comment: how can I implement it e.g. for the above script?

Comment: I prefer to copy, paste the references from word to LaTeX as well since it is only 9, but the problem is I can't make the quotation marks even with \say{x} in the bibliography. how to achieve that? can you modify above code showing me how to use quotes alike?

Comment: Or just use two backticks for the opening quotation marks and two straight quotes for the closing quotation marks. For English, LaTeX will turn these into open and closing double quotation marks. `csquotes` is nice and what I use, although I use it with active quotes instead of `\enquote{...}` which obscures the source too much for my taste.

Comment: @cfr what is active quote command?

Comment: @Hans You can make certain characters into active quotes which have the effect, roughly, of `\enquote{...}` but just mark the start and end of the quote with the characters of your choice. `csquotes` then figures out how to interpret these based on the context and language (e.g. inner or outer quote, English or German or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following mwe you can see how to use package `csquotes` and the command `\enquote` to use the standard quotion mark or `\foreignquote{english}{text}` to quote `text` with `english` quotationmarks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{IEEEhowto:hans1}
N.~Name, \enquote{The M.Sc. Thesis Titles in quotation}, M.Sc. Thesis, Y University, ISBN, City, Country, Year.
\bibitem{IEEEhowto:hans2}
R.~Name, \foreignquote{english}{The PhD Thesis Titles in quotation}, PhD Thesis, Y University, ISBN, City, Country, Year.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be several ways to achieve this.  As a starter kit:

- As your MWE indicates, your references are already formatted some way.  Try "text2bib", either locally ([from CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/text2bib)) or from the developper's dedicated [website](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/).
- If you have a large number of references and the original publications (like publications in journals) as a pdf file, let upload/past them into a literature reference managment software capable to i) fetch the bibliographic data and ii) export a *.bib file in either BibTeX or BibLaTeX dialect. 

   For publications already saved on your computer, a local installation of [Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/), or browser based solution [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) comes to my mind here.  Based on [doi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier), [zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) may fetch the bibliographic data for already saved papers, and assist in building your literature data base while accessing new publications, too.

Comment: thanks fot the info. As I commented to @Kurt: I prefer to copy, paste the references from word to LaTeX since it is only 9, but the problem is I can't make the quotation marks even with \say{x} in the bibliography. how to achieve that? can you modify above code showing me how to use quotes alike?

Comment: Kurt comment to my post has solved the quotation issue.