# Adding References/Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, msword

I have a long list of references (about 5 pages on Word), and I want to add this to a Latex file I have. I understand that I would have to create a `.bib` file and import that into my latex file with the `bibliography` package. But to do so, I would have to add each reference by hand and categorise them under article, year, author and so on.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Yes. There is lots of software out there that will create the .bib file for you (and help you keep track of your books, notes, etc. The earlier you use a program like that in your writing process, the better.) If you are looking for free software, I personally recommend  `Zotero` (available for most current operating systems.) You can edit each item (book, articles in journals, etc.) individually, but it's usually sufficient to provide an ISBN or DOI and it will fill in most fields automatically. There are many others, of course  (Mendeley, JabRef, Endnote, Citavi …) both free and commercial.

Comment: Online tool given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270035/transfering-references-from-ms-word-to-latex-bibliography) or Suggestions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270035/transfering-references-from-ms-word-to-latex-bibliography may helo you.

Comment: @Ubaidulla, did you mean for both links to be the same? I am looking up on the earlier thread but I'm a little confused about the online tool?